# Changing column names of a matrix in R without using colnames()

Tags: r

im new to R and was wondering if there is a way to assign names to columns in a matrix without using the colnames() function

```r
#creating two vectors 
player <- c(rep('dark',5),rep('light',5))
piece <-c('king','queen','pawn','pawn','knight','bishop','king','rook','pawn','pawn')

#creating a matrix
matrix2 <- c(player, piece)
dim(matrix2) <- c(10, 2)

#this would work perfectly but i was looking for an alternate method which doesn't uses 
#colnames() function
colnames(matrix2) <- c('player','piece')
```

I also know that using cbind() would give me a matrix with column names as those of the two vectors

```
matrix2<-cbind(player,piece)
```

But I don't want to create my matrix with the cbind() function. I wanted to know if there is a way to name the colunmns of the matrix other than using the colnames() function after creating the matrix like I have created above.

Comment: I just don't understand the question.  What all functions should not be used?

Comment: Does `matrix` be used in constructing `matrix` i.e. `matrix(c(player, piece), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("player", "piece")))`

Comment: While not using cbind() and colnames() functions. assign names c('player','piece') to the 2 columns of matrix2 after it has been created as shown in the question body

Comment: no you can assume that the matrix has already been created and you just need to name it's two columns but without using the colnames() function.

Comment: What about `matrix(c(player, piece), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("player", "piece")))`

Comment: Can I know why  you don't want to use `colnames` (which seems to be most direct option)

Comment: well honestly i have an assignment of R in which it is stated that you have to find two different  ways to assign names to the columns of the matrix2  after it has been created and you can't change the way it has been created. One way which i knew was using colnames()  but i can't find a second way to assign it

Comment: @akrun I voted to undelete your answer, it's essentially correct. My answer would be `cbind(player, piece)`, the colnames are automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to answer. Do you mean like this?

```
dimnames(matrix2) <- list(c(1:10), c("player", "piece"))
```

EDIT, without "naming" `row_names` (see comments, @akrun mentioned that earlier):

```
dimnames(matrix2) <- list(NULL, c("player", "piece"))
```

Comment: No not like that , as  your answer code is also naming the rows  and I was  looking for a solution that should output the same when  using the colnames() function

Comment: I think the OP meant `list(NULL, c("player", "piece"))`

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote the arguments to make clear how it works. Now? Not naming rows is easy, just use `NULL`instead, as @akrun suggested in two of the comments (see EDIT).

Comment: @RuiBarradas I noticed only after I wrote the soluiton, but  when I posted the solution I was thinking that cbind can be used, which I read incorrectly